# Best solution to get an output of multiple db tables on a page: PHP5(Kohana), MySQL

Tags: php, sql, architecture

I'm building social network from scratch on PHP5 (Kohana3) + MySQL and need to find the best solution to print user messages along with the comments, message refeneces, news and some other similiar stuff in one facebook-like line.

Comments and message_references belong to messages.

What would be better, to receive the data from every table in seperate arrays on data using simple select statements and then array_push them in one and use multiple foreach'es to build output or use some complex sql to get it?

There is an opinion:
"Add new message - and you must refresh whole cached data instead of just adding cache for a new message – biakaveron Jun 11 at 19:17"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a feed table and a feed repository class which all other parts of the system use to create feed items.

**Update**

Your comment module would to like this:

```
$feedRepository->Save($userId, 'comment', 
          "<a href='/users/view/$authorId'>$authorName</a>".
          " wrote a comment saying bla bla bla");
```

Where `$userId` is the id of the user that got a comment. `'comment'` is the module that made the entry.

Comment: you mean it would be some generated html stored in DB that represents data collected from all sources?